# Angular.dart vs Dart.js

Tags: dart, angular-dart

James De Boer had a seminar within the last two months stating at the onset that [Dart Is Angular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqKUTGB-CxA) only to end that seminar 30 some odd minutes later saying Angular is not Dart.js. That perplexity was not well appreciated.

I am totally confused. Should I learn Angular.Dart or should I learn Dart.JS?

```
var angular;
var dartJs;
var default;

String WhatisRight = function(){
  var rightAnswer;
  default = "angular.dart";
  default= "dartJs";
  return rightAnswer;
 }
```

Comment: I think he just meant "Dart, it's an awesome way to use Angular"

Comment: No he did not, he told me to use polymers, not directives. He basically told me to forget everything I learned. Google is not doing a very good job in showing me the way the trend is flowing.

Comment: Did you mean: "Should I learn Angular.Dart or should I learn __Angular__.JS?"

Answer (score 2):

There is no DartJs. There is a dart2js tool that compiles dart applications to javascript, and there is AngularDart, a version of Angular written in Dart.

Then there is [PolymerDart](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/polymer-intro/), an implementation of [web components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/). Angular and Polymer have intersecting functionalities, but [can be used together](http://blog.sethladd.com/2014/02/angular-and-polymer-data-binding.html).

It is a perfectly normal workflow to use AngularDart as application framework, PolymerDart to create custom components and compile the application to javascript with dart2js. They are not mutually exclusive.

I think maybe you attribute the @NgComponent annotation to PolymerDart, but it is part of AngularDart.